# Process End Wait for Exit

Tags: c#, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a windows App in C#. The button click to open a .bat file and run the script. When I do this:

```
var proc = Process.Start(@"filelocation.bat");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

It doesn't work for me. when I click the script from the folder works fine. From button click it opens for few seconds and close the window.

Comment: Then it sounds like your app isnt thinking the current directory is where that filelocation.bat is .....

Comment: I also tried to move whole script folder in C# project - resource folder. Then reference that path in the button click - same results. It opens individuality but closes from the app. How do I make app know the current directory?

Comment: Read up on the process class - it has many options one of which is where it starts

Comment: I think @BugFinder is right.  You need to create an instance of `ProcessStartInfo` class and set the `WorkingDirectory` property and then start the process passing that into the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
This following one worked for me! 
using System.Diagnostics;
public void ExecuteBatFile()
        {
            Process proc = null;
            string _batDir = string.Format(@"C:\"); //File path Location
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = _batDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "myfile.bat"; // Batch File name
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```